# python popen stdout strderr return from ssh

Tags: python, popen, stderr

I have a funtion which builds a ssh sommand lines and passes this to popen so I can run commands on a remote box ( I know I could use Fabirc or paramiko but for interests sake I wanted to do this).

so the fuction call is a wrapper arround Poepn (partly)

`def runcmd(cmd, host=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, both=None, shell=None, user=None)`

I invoke it for test with
runcmd('cd ~/app-scripts; grep "below and commment" *',user="testuser")

and the command it build up is shown as

`ssh -F /home/testuser/.ssh/config testuser@localhost 'cd ~/app-scripts; grep "below and commment" *'`

This runs on the "remote" host fine and the stdout correctly show the results -- 
however the stderr also contains all the  login messages from the remote host.

The internal fuction call to Popen is

`p = Popen(sshcmd,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
stdout_data,stderr_data = p.communicate()`

What am i missing?

Comment: if your `stderr_data` is not an empty string `''`, it means your command does't run successfully and  `p.returncode` is not 0. is it 0 in your scrpt?

Comment: tested by ading a print p.return code - as expected the command runs coreclty and returns 0. I suspect this a ssh thing which I am investigating.`>>> (out,err) = runcmd('cd ~/app-scripts; git status',user="testuser",both=True)
return code is 0` `>>> print err
['#######################################################', '#                                                     #', '#                       WARNING                       #', '#                 PROPRIETARY SYSTEM` `>>> print out
['# On branch master', 'nothing to commit (working directory clean)']`

Comment: when run multi-command in `Popon`, if the last command run successfully, the `p.returncode` is 0 even some previous commands failed, so try to run only one command  at a time to see what happened.

Comment: So - to answer my own question - sshd config had banner set on the remote host - setting -o LogLevel=Error returns the errors  but not the banner.

Comment: @LFJ - but the command didnt fail in the first instance. I run it with a command that I know will fail and the return code is as expected.`>>> runcmd('cd ~/scripts; git status',user="testuser",both=True)
return code is 128
([], ['#######################################################', '#                                                     #', '#                WARNING                       #', '#                 PROPRIETARY SYSTEM                  #', '#                                                      '', '', '', 'fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git']`